# Python: Processing Javascript with urllib2?

Tags: javascript, python, urllib2

I am coding a HTML scraper which gets values from a table on a website. I also need to grab the URL of an image, but the problem is this image is dynamically generated via javascript - and when i get contents of the website via urllib, the Javascript does not run or show in the resulting HTML.

Is there any way to enable Javascript to run on pages which are accessed via urllib?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you'd need some sort of JS interpreter for that. There might be Python-Browser integrations to help parsing this kind of page.