# beautiful soup HREF not found when capitalized

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, href

Hi i have something along the lines of:

```
from BeautifulSoup import BeautifulSoup as bs  
import urllib2

url = 'http://www.blah.com'  
soup = bs(urllib2.urlopen(url))

for link in soup.findAll('a', href=True):
   print link
```

So the problem is that the website uses both href and HREF (capitalized) for the links.  This script only pulls the href.  How would i modify the code also get the links with HREF?

Thanks

Comment: Can you post the sample page? I tested this code with `<a href="FOO">test1</a><a HREF="FOO">test2</a>` and it worked fine.

Comment: Thanks!  You made me double check.  Yes it does indeed work for both.  So what happened is that the links were not even being populated from urllib2.urlopen on the page b/c those links get generated via javascript:

    function getDoc(docid, fname){
      document.docform.doc.value=docid;
      document.docform.action='/docdownload/' + docid + '/' + fname;
      document.docform.submit();
    }

I think I am going to try this solution out [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4720342/python-processing-javascript-with-urllib2)

Comment: Just figure out what the JS is doing. You could use a headless Webkit browser and execute the JS, but it might be easier to just dissect the JS.